# duplicate item in dropdownlist edit mode in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Im trying to populate one of my gridview column with dropdownlist in edit mode. But it is showing a duplicate item which is the original value of that row before edit mode. How can i remove the duplicate item in edit mode's dropdownlist?

Normal Mode:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBRnm.jpg

Edit Mode:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2jQ3.jpg

These are my codes:

```
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
        {
            DataRowView drv = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;

            DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddl");
            ddl.DataTextField = "Name";
            ddl.DataValueField = "CategoryID";
            ddl.DataSource = Seminar_ListDB.getAllSemList();
            ddl.DataBind();
            //ddl.SelectedValue = drv["CategoryID"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

> > ddl.Items.Clear();

before binding the Drop Down List.

**EDIT2:**

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
        {
            DataRowView drv = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;

            DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddl");
            ddl.DataTextField = "Name";
            ddl.DataValueField = "CategoryID";
            ddl.Items.Clear();//add this line
            ddl.DataSource = Seminar_ListDB.getAllSemList();
            ddl.DataBind();

            ddl.SelectedValue = drv["CategoryID"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

**EDIT1:**

```
DropDownList.SelectedValue="Your_Value"
or
Dropdownlist.Items.FindByValue("Your_Value").Selected = true;
or
DropDownList.SelectedValue = DropDownList.Items.FindByText("Your_Text").Value;
or
Dropdownlist.SelectedItem.Text="Your_Text";
```

Hide Item From DropDownList:

```
var item = DropDownList1.Items.Select(p=>p.value == Your_Value).first();
DropDownList1.Remove(item);
or
DropDownList1.Items.Remove(DropDownList1.Items.FindByValue("02"));
```

Comment: Instead of renaming it to something else..is there any way to hide/remove it totally?

Comment: I thought its just the first item has duplicates, i realised theres' more below, how can i detect those duplicates and remove them?

Comment: use `ddl.Items.Clear();`
before `ddl.DataSource = Seminar_ListDB.getAllSemList();`@ags

Comment: I realised its because datasource is joined with two tables and that causes duplicate, is there any simple way to filter the datasource and remove those duplicates?

Comment: using an `INNER JOIN` is the best option!

Comment: use `distinct ` keyword

e.g: `selecet distinct t1.name as name from table1 as t1  join table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id`

Comment: This is my result, http://i.imgur.com/78G8geY.jpg with duplicates on the categoryid column

Comment: put your `query` with `table structure` in you question.if possible then create http://www.SqlFiddle.com

Comment: I wanted two tables fields and without the duplicate of categoryid shown when i display the categoryid in the dropdownlist. Updated the sqlfiddle

Comment: try:
`select distinct c.CatName from Category as c join Seminar_List as s on 
c.CategoryId=s.CategoryId`

Fiddle here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1d158/3

Comment: So for the dropdownlist i have to databind it with another source that  only select the c.CatName? Then how can i bring that selectedvalue of the ddl out and so that i can use it in RowUpdating to update into my db?

Comment: This is my current code http://pastebin.com/J8S6CqRn , how can i capture the selectedvalue of the ddl in the gridview/datarowbound and pass it on for updating?

Comment: no idea,i'm unable to answer this question. 
decide what you really want google it.@ags

Answer (score 0):

In the query of `getAllSemList()` you can use the `DISTINCT` query like :

```
SELECT DISTINCT columns
FROM table_name
WHERE where_conditions
```

So even if you have multiple entries in your table it will only *one* copy of that row. This way your dropdown will not display same column values more than once!

**EDIT 1 :**

You can use another query , which will not insert duplicate entries in your table which is :

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO TableName (Column1, Column2) VALUES('Value1' , 'Value2')
```

Moreover if you have only *one row* of dropwdowns then you can simply update by

```
obj.COl1 = ddl1.SelectedValue.ToString();
obj.COL2 = ddl2.SelectedValue.ToString();
obj.COL3 = ddl3.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

And in the update query you can pass the whole object only to be updated as :

```
public int Update(MyClass obj){
//update query
      UPDATE Table1 set Col1 = @col1value, Col2 = @col2value...
    WHERE *condition* 
}
```

**EDIT 2 :**

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1d158/7) is the sql fiddle you need to bind with the datasource of the dropdown which contains you `CatName` .

The query returns `CategoryName` and `CategoryID`, what you should do is :

```
dropdown.DataTextField = "CatName";
dropdown.DataValueField = "CategoryID";
```

.
.
.
.
Doing this while updating , you will have a category id to update!

Comment: Its not working for me, is there any way to hide that item in the dropdownlist?

Comment: see my updated answer . But i would like to see the query that you are running in `getAllSemList()`

Comment: Select DISTINCT * from Seminar_List SL, Category C where SL.CategoryID=C.CategoryID

Comment: I would prefer using a join query here : `SELECT DISTINCT Seminar_List.* ,Category.* FROM Seminar_List  INNER JOIN Category ON Seminar_List.CategoryID = Category.CategoryID WHERE Seminar_List.CategoryID = @categoryID`

Comment: ok, how can i get the selected value out and update to my db? I've these codes but doesn't work:

        List<Seminar_List> seminarList = Seminar_ListDB.getAllSemList();
        Seminar_List  sl = seminarList[e.RowIndex];
        sl.CategoryId = e.NewValues["CategoryID"].ToString();

Comment: getting the selected value from the dropdown is as simple as `int categoryID = Convert.ToInt32(dropwdownID.SelectedValue.ToString());` provided that your value field contains the `CategoryID`! Once you have `categoryID` you can simply perform an `INSERT` query!

Comment: My categoryid is a string and in the RowUpdating are those codes i pasted above, how can i pass the newly selected categoryid into rowupdating?

Comment: List<Seminar_List> seminarList = Seminar_ListDB.getAllSemList();
        Seminar_List  sl = seminarList[e.RowIndex];
        sl.Title = e.NewValues["Title"].ToString();
        sl.Description = e.NewValues["Description"].ToString();
        sl.Duration = e.NewValues["Duration"].ToString();
        sl.CategoryId = e.NewValues["CategoryID"].ToString();
        Seminar_ListDB.updateSeminarList(sl);

Comment: You are not editing anything into the dropdown right ? You are only *selecting* an option from drowpdown correct ?

Comment: Yes correct. selecting it and update the dbtable with the new selected value. Btw i just tried your inner join code, It is still showing duplicate categoryid in the dropdownlist, the distinct still doesn't work.

Comment: as I have mentioned earlier too either you should use `INSERT IGNORE...` OR `SELECT DISTINCT...` , either **should** do the job!

Comment: and in this case i would prefer you to remove duplicate entries first and use both the `INSERT IGNORE...` while inserting and `SELECT DISTINCT... ` while selecting the data

Comment: have you tried running the select distinct query in the query engine first ??

Comment: you can see there is multiple categoryid in the joined table.

Comment: USE : `SELECT DISTINCT table1.CategoryID, table1.Name... FROM table1 JOIN Table1.ID = Table2.ID WHERE _condition_`

Comment: see my updated question and this is the fiiddle you need for your dropdown :  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1d158/7

Comment: Hi thx for reply, i posted this latest question to here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29326673/getting-dropdownlist-selectedvalue-out-of-rowdatabound-into-rowupdating